# Web.xml error page definition precedence

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications

I've looked around for this, it seems it's not addressed. If in my webapp I've an error handling bit that goes

```
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error/maur_error.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
```

How is the precedence determined? In order of appearance?

EDIT: Please read carefully, there are **TWO** error page definitions

Comment: At one single point of time you may either have an exception or an error...you cannot have both at the same time...so there is no question of precedence..

Comment: No. you're not allowed to have a single `<error-page/>` with both, nothing stops you from having two of those handling the similar conditions

Answer (score 0):

If in your servlet you do 'response.sendError(500)', the user will see error.jsp. If, instead, you do 'throw new MyException()', the user will see maur_error.jsp. These are 2 different situations handled by 2 different pages.

The example with 500 and Throwable doesn't make a lot of sense indeed. But in another situation, e.g. AddressNotFoundException, SubscriptionExpiredException and 401 Not Authorized HTTP errror code (provided by app server, not by application) this mapping makes error handling easy.

Comment: Maybe my example was a little contrived. What I mean is if there are two error conditions for example an error-page for a `ViewExpiredException` (which will ordinarily result in an error code `500`) and another error-page def for http status code `500`, which error-page definition takes precedence, given that a `ViewExpiredException` naturally results in a `500`?

Comment: @kolossus, I think this situation is answered. If you throw a ViewExpiredException, the app goes to location defined in <exception-type>javax.faces.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>. If your application does response.sendError(500), the app goes to location defined by <error-code>500</error-code>. They are different error conditions handled by different handlers. Where is the precedence issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should not have precedence problem with your configuration, so ViewExpiredException should trigger a redirect to /error.jsp and 500 to /error/maur_error.jsp **exept if you have other error entry in your xml**.

e.g. I had a similar issue to yours (so ViewExpiredException -> wrong page) and it was because I had also this entry

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/genericError.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

As ViewExpiredException was wrapped in a more generic Exception, it was the Throwable entry thas was triggered.

In short, if you have a page for 500 error page defined, do not defined generic exception page. It is not needed and will 'eat' your more specific exception page.